# Why did Kim Ki-taek not just leave the house?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, ending, parasite

In [Parasite 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite_(2019_film)) Kim Ki-taek gets out of the basement to get the food at night. Why can't he just get out of the house and be free?

Answer (score 11):

As stated in [the Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite_(2019_film)#Plot) in your question:

> [he] is wanted for Mr. Park's murder.